# Why am i getting a unique key prop warning when i have a unique key?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import User from '../containers/User';
import './Sidebar.css';


const Sidebar = ({ contacts }) => {
return(
  <aside className="Sidebar">
      {contacts.map(contact => <User user={contact} key= 
      {contact.user_id} /> )}
   </aside>
 );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

I have a key for the User and i still get this warning and dom is not rendering the contacts.Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: the line break after '=' is not valid imho

Comment: that doesn't work. I still get the warning

Comment: Can you share the contacts array? maybe the have the same `user_id` (maybe its undefined even)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't see any mistake in the code posted regarding the key.

But there is a chance that the `user_id` passed in the contacts itself is duplicated, so that unique key warning might be appearing.

Irrespective of that warning, dom should be rendered as its a warning not an error.
So, for not rendering the dom there might be some other problems like User component not returning anything or like wise..

I tried locally with the Sidebar component shared, which worked fine.
If there is a fiddle for the problem it would be easy to identify the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Check this working example using your code. Hope it helps.

https://codesandbox.io/s/5w5v287lj4

```
import React from "react";
import User from "./User";

 const Sidebar = ({ contacts }) => {
  return (
   <div>
  {contacts.map(contact => (
    <User user={contact} key={contact.id} />
  ))}
</div>
);
 };
```

export default Sidebar;

```
<Sidebar contacts={contacts} />

import React from "react";

const User = ({ user }) => {
 return <div>{user.id}</div>;
};

export default User;
```

Answer (score 0):

As people said, it is likely that one of your userIds is duplicated.

To get rid of the warning you can build the key differently (but then you will loose some react optimization)

```
import React from 'react'
import User from '../containers/User'
import './Sidebar.css'

const Sidebar = ({ contacts }) => {
  return(
    <aside className="Sidebar">
      {contacts.map((contact, index) => <User user={contact} key={`${index}-${contact.user_id}`} />)}
    </aside>
  )
}

export default Sidebar
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the id has been duplicated.I found and got rid of it. Thank you guys!!!